# Python XlsxWriter ChartSheet watermark does not work

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I use python xlsxwriter to create PDF tables and graphs. There is a option to put watermark pictures by using the header.
This works fine for worksheets but it does not work for chartsheets. The header text is shown on both worksheets and chartsheets. The header image is only shown on the worksheet.

Anyone knows how to get a watermark on a chartsheet?

Here is an code example for this

```
    #######################################################################
#
# An example of creating an Excel chart in a chartsheet with Python
# and XlsxWriter.
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-2-Clause
# Copyright 2013-2023, John McNamara, jmcnamara@cpan.org
#
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("chartsheet.xlsx")

# Add a worksheet to hold the data.
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

worksheet.set_header('&C&G&LTEXTISVISIBLE', {'image_center': 'watermark_draft.png'})

# Add a chartsheet. A worksheet that only holds a chart.
chartsheet = workbook.add_chartsheet()

chartsheet.set_header('&C&G&LTEXTISVISIBLE', {'image_center': 'watermark_draft.png'})

# Add a format for the headings.
bold = workbook.add_format({"bold": 1})

# Add the worksheet data that the charts will refer to.
headings = ["Number", "Batch 1", "Batch 2"]
data = [
    [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [10, 40, 50, 20, 10, 50],
    [30, 60, 70, 50, 40, 30],
]

worksheet.write_row("A1", headings, bold)
worksheet.write_column("A2", data[0])
worksheet.write_column("B2", data[1])
worksheet.write_column("C2", data[2])


# Create a new bar chart.
chart1 = workbook.add_chart({"type": "bar"})

# Configure the first series.
chart1.add_series(
    {
        "name": "=Sheet1!$B$1",
        "categories": "=Sheet1!$A$2:$A$7",
        "values": "=Sheet1!$B$2:$B$7",
    }
)

# Configure a second series. Note use of alternative syntax to define ranges.
chart1.add_series(
    {
        "name": ["Sheet1", 0, 2],
        "categories": ["Sheet1", 1, 0, 6, 0],
        "values": ["Sheet1", 1, 2, 6, 2],
    }
)

# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
chart1.set_title({"name": "Results of sample analysis"})
chart1.set_x_axis({"name": "Test number"})
chart1.set_y_axis({"name": "Sample length (mm)"})

# Set an Excel chart style.
chart1.set_style(11)

# Add the chart to the chartsheet.
chartsheet.set_chart(chart1)

# Display the chartsheet as the active sheet when the workbook is opened.
chartsheet.activate()

workbook.close()
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this in Excel?

Comment: Thank @moken. I should have been more precise in my question. So it is *technically* possible to set the header and that is what the VBA code and XlsxWriter is doing. However, as far as I can see it isn't possible to display a header image like this *in Excel*. I'm open to correction here, and there may be a bug in XlsxWriter, but I don't think this actually works in Excel.

Comment: I believe it pretty much only gets seen when printed. Chartsheet doesn't enable 'Page Layout' View that sheets have so other than going into the header setup I don't think it's viewable in Excel. Anyway will leave it to the Poster to comment.

Comment: @jmcnamara
Not sure if we are missunderstanding, but for me it looks like this is possible in Excel. Click Insert > Header - Footer/Custom Header / Add Picture. And then i can see it in print preview or printed. (I do not use english Excel, so i hope, the description would fit to english excel version)

Comment: @bierpreis does the watermark actually display when you do that, in Excel?

Comment: @jmcnamara Not on the actual sheet in excel, but i can see it if i switch to print preview or print it (to pdf).

Comment: In that case it looks like a bug in XlsxWriter. I’ll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there was a bug in XlsxWriter that prevented header image from being added (fully) to chartsheets. That is fixed now on the GitHub main: https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter